# Run Airflow with docker-compose from a different folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

Using the `docker-compose.yml` from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) and running `docker-compose up` I am able to run Airflow without problems (Ubuntu). But this only works if the parent folder is named `/airflow`. If it is named something else, the `airflow-init` service will fail:

```
ERROR: for airflow-init  Container "f28089f55f79" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I want to be able to run Airflow using `docker-compose up` when my project lives in a different folder, e.g.: `myproject/docker-compose.yaml`

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

By checking [Apache airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html?highlight=airflow_home#envvar-AIRFLOW_HOME) page and the [docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/configuration.html) it says that `$AIRFLOW_HOME` by default is `~/airflow`

Just change this variable.